# Event Monitoring to capture record access

Tags: visualforce, eventlogfile

Is there anyway to capture who has accessed Salesforce records? Does Event Monitoring capture this event?

Answer (score 2):

The [URI_EVENT](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm#uri-event) log type records all UI accesses to any page at all, including records. Note that you can't just filter by a specific type (e.g. just event pages), so you'll need to do some post-processing.

Comment: Okay, the event log file does contain who and what record was access?? I can iterate over the log file that gets created.. I just want to capture if anyone opens a record.. Let me know...

Comment: @NoNicknameSFDC Basically, you get a CSV file, so you have to read the log as a CSV file, and `USER_ID` and `URI` values to determine which record(s) were accessed. The documentation basically covers everything you need to know.